# Density of a vector space generated by power functions

Tags: real-analysis

One example of this theorem wanted?

Suppose $ \lbrace\lambda_{j}\rbrace_{j=0}^{\infty} $ is a sequence
of distinct positive numbers. Then $\mathrm{span}\lbrace 1,x^{\lambda_{1}},\ldots\rbrace   $ is dense in $ C[0,1] $ if and only if
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\lambda_{j}}{\lambda_{j}^{2}+1}=\infty .
$$
Moreover, if
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\lambda_{j}}{\lambda_{j}^{2}+1}<\infty ,
$$
then every function from the $ C[0,1] $ closure of $\mathrm{span}\lbrace 1,x^{\lambda_{1}},\ldots\rbrace   $ can be represented as
an analytic function on $ \lbrace z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]\; :\; \vert z\vert<1\rbrace $ restricted to $ (0,1) $.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a particular title right there.